# i18n custom Exception Handlers not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I created a dummy rails 4.1.5 application in order to learn how to use a Different Exception Handler as explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-exception-handlers). I only add this file to the scaffold generated application:

```
#config/initializers/i18n.rb

module I18n
  class JustRaiseExceptionHandler < ExceptionHandler
    def call(exception, locale, key, options)
      puts ">>>>>>>>> #{exception.class}"
      super
    end
  end
end

I18n.exception_handler = I18n::JustRaiseExceptionHandler.new
```

In my console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.5)
irb(main):001:0> I18n.backend.store_translations :en, thanks: 'Thanks %{name}!'; nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> I18n.translate :thanks, name: 'john'
=> "Thanks john!"
irb(main):003:0> I18n.translate :foo, name: 'john'
>>>>>>>>> I18n::MissingTranslation
=> "translation missing: en.foo"
irb(main):004:0> I18n.translate :thanks, foo: 'john'
I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument: missing interpolation argument :name in "Thanks %{name}!" ({:foo=>"john"} given)
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:92:in `block in missing_interpolation_argument_handler'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb:29:in `call'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb:29:in `block in interpolate_hash'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb:21:in `gsub'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb:21:in `interpolate_hash'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb:17:in `interpolate'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:152:in `interpolate'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:41:in `translate'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:158:in `block in translate'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:154:in `catch'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:154:in `translate'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/masciugo/dev/ciccio/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/masciugo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'irb(main):005:0>
```

Why does not my custom handler get invoked in case of I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way Rails does not raise I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940385/way-rails-does-not-raise-i18nmissinginterpolationargument-exception)